# How can I put my countdown timer next to my question body in qualtrics?

Tags: css, countdowntimer, qualtrics

I want to put my countdown timer on my qualtrics survey next to the question body, that is to say, the question body and the timer are adjacent to each other. So my question won't be covered by the timer, but my timer will still remain in view. Is there a CSS code to do that?

I can now put the timer on top right and keep it fixed, the CSS in "look &feel" is as below. But I think it would be better to move the timer closer to the question body.I think the key trick is that now the position of the timer is relative to the question body.

```
.FlipClock {
background-color: #333;
padding: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 10px auto;
float: right;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML so that we can troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Sorry the html is too long. I don't think I can include it. Is there an alternative way to help understand the question?

Comment: You can simplify your code. Or you can try to include an image of either the code or the layout, or both.